# Why does Ivan believe Dmitri's ego will compel him to help the broken Dominika?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, red-sparrow

In *Red Sparrow 2018*, Dominika's uncle, Ivan Egorova speaks to Dominika Egorova

> State security is interested in knowing more about Dmitri Ustinov. You
>   met him at the Bolshoi. Remember? He likes you. A broken bird that he
>   could help. Something **his ego** won't be able to resist.

Why does Ivan believe Dmitri's ego will compel him to help the broken Dominika?

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't seen the movie, so maybe this will sound stupid but... Why wouldn't that guy have ego? Don't we all have a bit of ego...? Or is this about _what_ could be referred by "his ego"? If you want, you cna [edit] your question to clarify this. If this is just me not having seen it... Sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly obvious from what follows.

Dmitri is a sexual predator.  He can't resist imposing his dominance over someone weaker.  He does this initially under the guise of being helpful and benevolent, but this changes when he wants to extract emotional and sexual payment for his generosity.

Ivan understands that Dmitri's appetite is his weakness, one that Dominika can work on and exploit.